# How should the final round be carried out in Ticket To Ride?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

The rules state that when a player ends their turn with two wagons or less, the final turn begins and that all players will be entitled to their last turn.

In this case there are 5 players, the first to move is player 1, the last player is player 5.

If player 3 ends his turn with 2 wagons, what is the correct ending of the game?

1. Player 4 takes his last turn and so on until player 3 closes the game
2. Player 4 and Player 5 complete the round and then there will be one last turn for all 5 players
3. Player 4 and Player 5 complete the turn, and the game ends

In the first case, player 4 and 5 would play one turn less.

In the second case, everyone would play the same number of turns, but player 3 may not have any further moves available.

In the third case, players 1 and 2 would be unaware that this was their last hand, while 3, 4 and 5 would know.

Comment: There are _many_ variants of TTR, please be specific about exactly which one you are asking about.

Comment: @PhilipKendall whilst that is true, certain core mechanics (e.g. exchanging train cards for basic routes) are consistent. I'd have guessed that this would be one of those that doesn't vary

Comment: @PhilipKendall while the series is referred to as Ticket To Ride, that is also the name of the original version and variant, so it is possible they were being specific here.

Comment: Meta question here :) https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/what-should-the-ticket-to-ride-tag-represent

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### 1. Player 4 takes his last turn and so on until player 3 closes the game

The [manual for Ticket to Ride](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/fr/img/tt_rules_2015_en.pdf) says this:

> Game End
>
> > When one player’s stock of colored plastic trains gets down to only 0,1 or 2 trains left at the end of his turn, each player, including that player, gets
> > one final turn. The game then ends and players calculate their final scores.

This seems pretty clear, it doesn't matter which player started the game, only which player gets down to two or less trains for where the final round starts. Every player will know that it is their final turn and every player will get a turn in the final round.